# Python multi-line pattern matching

Tags: python, subprocess, pcregrep

I am trying to match a multiline pattern using a shell command through python.

I am able to match using the shell commands but I am not able to pass this command through the Python subprocess.call or the os.system modules.

My file looks something like this:

```
(CELL
  (CELLTYPE "NAND_2X1")
  (INSTANCE U2)
  (DELAY
    (ABSOLUTE
    (IOPATH A1 ZN (0.02700::0.02700) (0.01012::0.01012))
    (IOPATH A2 ZN (0.02944::0.02944) (0.00930::0.00930))
    )
  )
)
```

No, I am trying to extract this:

```
  (INSTANCE U2)
  (DELAY
    (ABSOLUTE
    (IOPATH A1 ZN (0.02700::0.02700) (0.01012::0.01012))
    (IOPATH A2 ZN (0.02944::0.02944) (0.00930::0.00930))
    )
  )
```

using this regex:

```
pcregrep -M -n 'INSTANCE U2((?!^\)).*\n)+' sdf/c1_syn_buf2.sdf
```

wherein U2 is the search string and sdf/c1_syn_buf2.sdf is the file name

In Python, I have defined a function to which I will pass the search string and the file name as I have to do this operation multiple times.

I am unable to successfully execute this as a shell command using something like:

```
>>>b = subprocess.call(['pcregrep','-M','-n','INSTANCE '+arg, '\)((?!^\).*\n)+ '+file ])
pcregrep: Failed to open \)((?!^\).*
)+ /home/sanjay/thesis/code/sdf/c7552_syn_buf0.sdf: No such file or directory
```

When I actually put in the argument (U2 in this case) name and the file name, I am able to get the desired output.

**EDIT**
If pcregrep is not friendly enough, here is the awk command:

```
awk '/INSTANCE U2/,/^)\n?/' sdf/c1_syn_buf2.sdf
```

Returns the same.

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: I think you just have a typo around: 
.*\n)+ '+file
It perhaps should be 
.*\n)+ ', file
with a comma instead of a plus

Comment: @rkh Its not a typo, the stuff in parentheses is basically saying `(.*\n)+`, I have added the `(?!\))` to indicate that matching needs to be done only until a line that starts with `)` is encountered.

Comment: The comma separating arg from '\) should also be a +, I think, so that the element in the list is a single argument to the subprocess call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run the shell command:

```
$ pcregrep -M -n 'INSTANCE U2((?!^\)).*\n)+' sdf/c1_syn_buf2.sdf
```

in Python:

```
from subprocess import check_output as qx

output = qx(['pcregrep', '-M', '-n', r'INSTANCE {}((?!^\)).*\n)+'.format(arg),
             path_to_sdf])
```

- use `r''` literal or double all backslashes
- pass each shell argument as a *separate* list item

Also, you don't need `pcregrep`, you could search the file in Python:

```
import re
from mmap import ACCESS_READ, mmap

with open(path_to_sdf) as f, mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=ACCESS_READ) as s:
    # arg = re.escape(arg) # call it if you want to match arg verbatim
    output = re.findall(r'INSTANCE {}((?!^\)).*\n)+'.format(arg).encode(), s,
                        flags=re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
```

`mmap` is used to accommodate files that do not fit in memory. It also might run faster on Windows.

Comment: @Sebastian I'm fairly new to python, hence was using Unix commands..thanks for the mmap approach, it works perfectly! Thanks for the perl like approach to qx

Answer (score 1):

Just looking at your original command line, and formatting the call to one arg per line, should it not be this?

```
b = subprocess.call(
['pcregrep',
    '-M',
    '-n',
    'INSTANCE {}\)((?!^\)).*\n)+ '.format(arg),
    file ])
```

I am not so sure about the parenthesis and the backslashes.  Those are always a bit tricky in regexes.  You might have to fiddle with them a bit to get exactly what you want (look in the python documentation for the r'' regex string type)

Comment: I did not get this one, I would like to have the `arg` in the search string

Comment: the format line will put arg in the search string.  If arg is set to "Hello", then 'INSTANCE {}\)((?!^\).*\n)+ '.format(arg) is equal to 'INSTANCE hello\)((?!^\).*\n)+ ' (plus or minus some backslashes)

Comment: hmm...I actually just tried it and now pcregrep reports the error:
`>>> b = subprocess.call(['pcregrep','-M','-n','INSTANCE {}\)((?!^\).*\n) '.format(arg),file ])
pcregrep: Error in command-line regex at offset 25: missing )`

Comment: I wish there was a simple backtick or exec method for Python like perl!

Comment: looking at your original regex, I think I forgot an extra ')' in the middle.  I have just edited.  Hopefully the backslashes are correct...

Comment: note: `len('\n') == 1` and `len(r'\n') == 2`. Use `r''` literals if you want to pass `\n` to `pcregrep`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I need to use format specifiers `%s`

It works when I use:

```
b = subprocess.check_output("pcregrep -M -n 'INSTANCE '%s'((?!^\)).*\n)+' {} ".format(file) %arg,shell=True)
```

With this, I get the exact match into the variable `b`

I am passing the argument using %s and the file name using the `{} .format` method

Comment: you should use either `%` or `.format` string formatting. Using both at the same time looks ugly.